# Given languages A,B and C, each with alphabet Σ, define A/B/C as:

Tags: context-free

Given languages A,B and C, each with alphabet Σ, define A/B/C as

A/B/C = { w∈Σ* | ∃u ∈ B and ∃v ∈ C; such that wuv ∈ A }.
Prove that if A is context-free, and B and C are regular, then A/B/C is context-free.